# How to translate these inspirational phrases correctly?

Tags: translation, grammar, meaning-in-context, traditional-characters, idioms

I'm trying to make a label for my workbook but I'm not very sure how to write this phrase:

```
If you can dream it you can do it!.
```

Using google translate (traditional chinese) renders me this result:

```
如果你能做到夢想就可以做到！
```

The other phrase I want to translate is: (Again accompanied by google translate results)

```
Best of luck in Mathematics and Science!

祝你好運數學和科學！
```

Note: The meaning of this second sentence is referring to those different courses or subjects. Hence assistance is needed.

```
You're the number one student!

你是頭號學生
```

I'm not sure if these results are gramatically correct or if they do really mean what it was intended to say in english. Can somebody help me with a proper check and review of these?.

Edit:

I'd like to get some help with translating the second sentence as it was left unattended by one of the answers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. 有夢即成。2. 數學科學一切順利。3. 名列前茅。

Comment: @young99 Perhaps can you explain a little bit the second phrase?. I can understand, mathematics science all the best. Does it exist a subject and a predicate and verb in the phrase the way you wrote it?. I would like to be sure if it is grammatically correct. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 3):

> If you can dream it you can do it!
>   梦得到的都做得到！ (what can be dreamed of can be done!)

梦得到的 that which can be dreamed (the 的 changes 梦得到 "can be dreamed" to "that which can be dreamed")
都 all (adverb)
做得到 can be done

verb得到 means "able to successfully verb". The opposite is verb不到. This is called the "potential complement" and is a common grammar pattern.

> You're the number one student!
>   你是最佳学生！

你
是 are
最佳学生 best student (最佳X is a commmon pattern meaning best X, often used for best player in a football team etc)

> Best of luck in Mathematics and Science!

This one's a bit trickier. Do you mean "best of luck in the Mathematics and Science exam"? (or are they two different courses?). Or do you mean good luck with the course in general, not specifically the exam?

Comment: I meant good luck with those courses, in other words your second guess (not the exam), they are two different subjects. Can you please tell me which is the predicate and the subject?. I'd like to learn how to distinguish these in the sentences you had translated.

Comment: I edited some explanation into the answer.

Comment: There is yet the last phrase (best of luck). I mean the one which you mentioned that was trickier, with the clarification can it help the translation?. For the explanation of the other two, thanks.

Comment: Perhaps can you add a translation for the second phrase?. I'm still doubtful what would it be correct. Some other user has made a suggestion in the comments, but I'm still not sure. Can you verify?.

Comment: Yeah, the other user's suggestion looks good for that. You can add a 祝你 (wishing you) to the beginning if you want. 祝你数学科学一切顺利 means something like "wishing you maths and science everything smooth", or more idiomatically "hope everything goes well for you in maths and science". I believe that captures the spirit of your original sentence quite well.

Comment: By the way I've just noticed I've been using simplified characters while your post used traditional. My apologies. Hope that does not cause you any problems. There are converters you can find on google that let you paste text in to change from one to the other.

Comment: Yes you did wrote simplified instead of traditional (which was intended as the request). I did some research on my own and the phrases you wrote in traditional would be: 1. 夢得到的都做得到！(If you can dream it you can do it!) - I couldn't find a difference in those. Then using the other user's suggestion and your addition 2. 祝你數學科學一切順利 (wishing you maths and science everything smooth) 3. 你是最佳學生！ (You're the number one student!). For these last two there was a difference in the character 學 xue for learn. But I'm a novice I would like you could review if those are correct. Are they?.

Comment: 数学 and 科学 are nouns ,and 学生 is also a noun. 学 is not use as a verb learn here.